# How to add random points in between the given points?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scatter

I have data points as dataframe just like represented in figure1

sample data

```
df= 
74  34  
74.5    34.5    
75  34.5    
75  34  
74.5    34  
74  34.5    
76  34  
76  34.5    
74.5    34  
74  34.5    
75.5    34.5    
75.5    34  
75  34  
75  34.5
```

I want to add random points in between those points but keep the shape of the initial points.
Desired output will be somehow like in figure 2 (black dots represent the random points.And the red line represent the boundary)

~Any suggestions? I am looking for a general solution since the geometry of the outer boundary will change in problem

[image: Figure1_input]

[image: Figure2_Desired_output]

Comment: Checkout the wikipedia article on [Orthorngonal convex hulls] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_convex_hull)

Answer (score 0):

If the shape is convex it is pretty simple:

```
def get_random_point(points):
    point_selectors = np.random.randint(0, len(points), 2)
    scale = np.random.rand()#value between 0 and 1
    start_point = points[point_selectors[0]]
    end_point = points[point_selectors[1]]
    return start_point + (end_point - start_point) * scale
```

The shape you have specified is not convex. But without you additionally specifying which points make up the exterior of your shape or additional constraints like e.g. you only want to allow for lines to go parallel to either x or y axis the shape you see is mathematically not sufficiently specified.

Final remark: There are algorithms which can check whether a point is within a polygon ([Point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)).
You can then 1) specify bounding polygon 2) generate a point within the bounding rectangle of your shape and 3) test whether the point lies within the shape of your polygon.

Answer (score 0):

interpolation might be worth looking into:

```
import numpy as np

# lets suppose y = 2x and x[i], y[i] is a data point
x = [1, 5, 16, 20, 60] 
y = [2, 10, 32, 40, 120]

interp_here = [7, 8, 9, 21] # the points where we are going to interpolate values.

print(np.interp(interp_here, x, y))  ## [14. 16. 18. 42.]
```

If you want random points, then you could use the above as a guide line and then for each point add/subtract some delta.